# визуальная новелла на HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, after-effects

У меня есть идея, создать страничку в  духе визуальных новелл фотография с персонажем который моргает, качает головой и рядом кнопки с вопросами по типу "какое твое хобби, сильные и слабые стороны"

Персонажа должным образом анимировал в After Effects но при добавлении на сайт с помощью bodymovin  ничего не происходит (в консоле на объектах svg видно что анимация работает но ничего не происходит)

Есть идеи как можно реализовать мою задумку, какие-то способы анимировать изображение?

Comment: Ну не знаю, я никаких ошибок не вижу, вроде всё работает как положено)

Comment: У меня тоже все работает